# input and when steps in stage

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I'm trying to create a conditional deploy stage within a declarative pipeline; what I've got is:

```
pipeline {

    agent any

    stages {

        stage("Push Large Binaries") {
            input {
                message "Should we push the large binaries?"
                parameters {
                    booleanParam(
                        name: '_PUSH',
                        defaultValue: true,
                        description: 'set to true to push the docker image')
                }
            }
            when {
                expression {
                     _PUSH == true
                }
            }
            steps {
                echo "hi ${_PUSH}"
                echo "pushing..."'
            }
        }

        stage("Say Goodbye"){
            steps {
                echo "Goodbye!"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

for some strange reason, while the `echo` statement does show correctly `true` or `false` depending on the user selection, the stage is always executed, regardless of whether the `_PUSH` tick-box is unticked

any idea what's wrong with the code?

thanks you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Always consider what is "behind" which is Java and you have to play with types, in this case you issue is related that you are matching it vs a Boolean but instead If you match the equality as a String then you will get what you are expecting.

```
pipeline {

    agent any

    stages {

        stage("Push Large Binaries") {
            input {
                message "Should we push the large binaries?"
                parameters {
                    booleanParam(
                        name: '_PUSH',
                        defaultValue: true,
                        description: 'set to true to push the docker image')
                }
            }
            when {
                expression {
                     _PUSH == "true" // Match to a String
                }
            }
            steps {
                echo "hi ${_PUSH}"
                echo "pushing..."
            }
        }

        stage("Say Goodbye"){
            steps {
                echo "Goodbye!"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

An alternative which you will get is a Boolean. Please, notice If you want a "input" that prompts you for many values then it will return a Map instead of Boolean. :

```
pipeline {

    agent any

    stages {

        stage("Push Large Binaries") {
            steps {
                script {
                    inputData = input message: 'Should we push the large binaries?', parameters: [booleanParam(defaultValue: false, description: 'set to true to push the docker image', name: '_PUSH')]
                    if(inputData) {
                        echo "Hi ${inputData}"
                        echo "Pushing ..."
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        stage("Say Goodbye"){
            steps {
                echo "Goodbye!"
            }
        }
    }
}
```